# I'm unable to launch apache ODE

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, apache-ode

I'm using eclipse to create a BPEL project
my environment is:
eclipse kepler
bpel visual designer 1.0.5
apache-cxf-3.1.4-src
tomcat 8.0.28-r2

I was following the tutorial at :
http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/SIMBAD/courses/doku.php?id=teaching_assistant:bpel:deploying_hello_world_bpel_process_with_eclipse_bpel_designer_and_apache_ode

trying to create the hello world example, at the step where I launch the ODE server I get:

```
Dec 27, 2015 2:52:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat-8/${gentoo.classpath}], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 27, 2015 2:52:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
```

the directory /usr/share/tomcat-8/ is the tomcat home dir
I'm not sure what the ${gentoo.classpath} is (env variable?)

I'm new to the BPEL designer and apache ODE
let me know if additional info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ODE issue.
You could probably deploy ODE war in an external Tomcat Server. Design your processes in Eclipse and deploy the process archive to ODE running in external Tomcat.